# How to Flatten data along with key in Lumen/Laravel

Tags: php, lumen, flatten, json-flattener

I followed [this](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-collection-flatten-method-exampleexample.html) tutorial. It was worked. How to get json to flatten along with key in lumen/laravel. I need key and value.

Code I used:

```
public function index(){
$collection = collect([
        'name' => 'Hardik', 
        'role' => ['admin', 'manager', 'superadmin'],
        'multi' => 
            [
                'one',
                'two' => ['two1', 'two3'],
                'three'
            ],
    ]);

$flattened = $collection->flatten();
      
dd($flattened);
}
```

Actual Output:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object(

[items:protected] => Array

    (

        [0] => Hardik

        [1] => admin

        [2] => manager

        [3] => superadmin

        [4] => one

        [5] => two1

        [6] => two3

        [7] => three

    ))
```

Here the keys coming as integer from 0. But I need it as the key from the array.

Output expected:

```
  ['name'] => Hardik

    ['role'] => admin

    ['role'] => manager

    ['role'] => superadmin

    ['multi.one'] => one

    ['multi.two'] => two1

    ['multi.two'] => two3

    ['multi.three'] => three
```

How to get it?

Comment: Can you share what type of output do you want?

Comment: You can't transforming to your expected output. Please check your array. Please give a valid array.

Comment: I am not transforming. I am having collectin with keys. expecting output as it is.

Comment: But you can't. Check your array.